# Diferença entre duas datas em dias, horas, minutos e segundos

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Problema: Como realizar a subtração entre duas datas  e retornar o valor em Dias, Horas, Minutos e Segundos em uma consulta SQL com SQL Server 2014?

**Exemplo:**

```
Dados:

DataRecebimento          DataEnvio
2013-11-29 11:30:40.157  2014-05-27 14:10:50.637
2013-11-29 17:30:40.157  2014-05-27 14:10:50.637

Resultado pretendido (intervalo entre as datas):
179d 03:40:10
178d 21:40:10
```

Comment: Veja se este link esclarece sua dúvida http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. Usa MySQL, SQLServer, etc? [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Via TransactSQL, use `DATEDIFF`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Fiz alguns calculos com data:
http://adjuniordba.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/calculo-simples-de-data/ []´s

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DECLARE @antes DATETIME = '2013-11-29 11:30:40.157';
DECLARE @depois DATETIME = '2014-05-27 14:10:50.637';

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(DAY, @antes, @depois)) + 'd '
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, @antes, @depois) % 24), 2) + ':'
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @antes, @depois) % 60), 2) + ':'
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @antes, @depois) % 60), 2);
```

Ou em forma de função abaixo (com tratamentos adicionais):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCalculaTempo 
(
    @antes DATETIME, @depois DATETIME
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp DATETIME;
    IF (@antes > @depois)
    BEGIN
        SET @temp = @antes;
        SET @antes = @depois;
        SET @depois = @temp;
    END
    RETURN  CASE WHEN @temp IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '-' END
            + CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, @antes, @depois) <> 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(DAY, @antes, @depois)) + 'd ' ELSE '' END
            + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, @antes, @depois) % 24), 2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @antes, @depois) % 60), 2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @antes, @depois) % 60), 2);
END
GO
```

Testes com valores negativos (@depois antes de @antes):

```
SELECT dbo.fnCalculaTempo('2013-11-29 11:30:40.157', '2014-05-27 14:10:50.637');
SELECT dbo.fnCalculaTempo('2013-11-29 17:30:40.157', '2014-05-27 14:10:50.637');
SELECT dbo.fnCalculaTempo('2013-11-29 17:30:40.157', '2013-11-29 18:34:00.249');
SELECT dbo.fnCalculaTempo('2014-11-29 11:30:50.157', '2014-11-29 10:30:50.637');
SELECT dbo.fnCalculaTempo('2014-11-29 10:30:50.157', '2014-11-28 10:30:40.637');
```

Comment: ^^ hehehe tirou minhas duvidas, só melhorando um pouquinho a query, pela lógica se eu tenho um horário no *@depois menor que no *@antes eu não tenho um dia corrido ainda. O DATEDIFF tem esse bug ao calcular os dias corridos, e era isso que tava me matando.... Desculpem se eu não expressei minha duvida mais claramente, pois tinha ficado a sexta feira inteira quebrando a cabeça.

Comment: @Fredguapo, troquei a função para que ela tratasse os valores negativos. Acho que faz mais sentido e é mais simples trocar os valores antes, dá uma olhada em como ficou. A alteração que você tinha sugerido fazia com que quando tivesse 1 hora negativa passasse a mostrar 1 dia e 1 hora negativos.

Answer (score 5):

Este código está errado no cálculo da diferença de horas. A diferença da hora deve ser assim:

```
+ RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @antes, @depois) / 60), 2) + ':'
```

Pois no seguinte exemplo:

```
SELECT (SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR,'2015-05-03 10:42:00','2015-05-03 12:00:00')) % 24)
```

O `select` acima vai retornar 2 horas e o `select` abaixo vai retornar corretamente 1 hora, pois a diferença é de 1 hora e 18 minutos.

```
SELECT (SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2015-05-03 10:42:00','2015-05-03 12:00:00')) / 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei essa solução para o problema das horas:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 2013-11-29 11:30:40.157, 2014-05-27 14:10:50.637) / 60 / 60 / 24))
                    + 'd ' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS(((DATEDIFF(SECOND, 2013-11-29 11:30:40.157, 2014-05-27 14:10:50.637) / 60) / 60) % 24)), 2) 
                    + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS((DATEDIFF(SECOND, 2013-11-29 11:30:40.157, 2014-05-27 14:10:50.637) / 60) % 60)), 2) 
                    + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 2013-11-29 11:30:40.157, 2014-05-27 14:10:50.637) % 60)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo com a correção proposta na resposta número 3, a função não retorna os valores corretos. Segue a função com alterações na forma de cálculo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnComputeDateDiff
(
    @dtStartDate DATETIME, @dtEndDate DATETIME, @Mode CHAR
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp DATETIME;
    DECLARE @Days    INT
    DECLARE @Hours   INT
    DECLARE @Minutes INT
    DECLARE @Seconds INT
    DECLARE @TotalSeconds INT
    DECLARE @Ret VARCHAR(20)

    SET @Ret = ''

    IF (@dtStartDate IS NOT NULL AND @dtEndDate IS NOT NULL AND @Mode IN ('H','D'))
       BEGIN
          IF (@dtStartDate > @dtEndDate)
             BEGIN
                 SET @temp = @dtStartDate;
                 SET @dtStartDate = @dtEndDate;
                 SET @dtEndDate = @temp;
             END

          SET @TotalSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)

          SET @Days = @TotalSeconds / 86400
          SET @TotalSeconds = @TotalSeconds % 86400
          SET @Hours = @TotalSeconds / 3600
          SET @TotalSeconds = @TotalSeconds % 3600
          SET @Minutes = @TotalSeconds / 60
          SET @Seconds = @TotalSeconds % 60

          IF @Mode = 'H'
             BEGIN
                SET @Hours = @Hours + @Days * 24
                SET @Days = 0
             END

          SET @Ret = CASE @Days WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE RTrim( Convert(Char,@Days)) + ' d ' END
          SET @Ret = @Ret + Right(RTrim(Convert(Char,@Hours)),10) + ':'
          SET @Ret = @Ret + Right('00' + RTrim(Convert(Char,@Minutes)),2) + ':'
          SET @Ret = @Ret + Right('00' + RTrim(Convert(Char,@Seconds)),2)

       END

    RETURN @Ret
END

GO
```

Comment: Ao ler a sua resposta fiquei na dúvida se este código está ou não correcto ou apenas incorpora a correcção proposta na resposta 3. Quando fizer referência a um outro poste faça-o indicando o nome do autor, porque a numeração das respostas depende da opção de ordenação.

Comment: Note que o número que aparece na resposta é o número de votos e não o número de sequência.

Answer (score 0):

Versão mais compacta:

```
SELECT FORMAT(FLOOR(CAST(@depois-@antes AS FLOAT)),'0d ')+FORMAT(@depois-@antes,'hh:mm:ss')
```

A MS, numa série de produtos, define internamente a data como o número de dias desde 1/1/1900. A diferença entre duas data resulta precisamente na diferença de dias.