# Diferença entre dias horas e minutos no Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tenho duas  colunas do tipo `datetime`. Já tentei de várias  maneiras pegar a diferença entre elas, porém o número de dias sempre sai incorreto.

Exemplo:

```
Data1: 2018-01-17 17:00:00
Data2: 2018-01-18 10:00:00

Resultado obtido:  01 17:00:00
Resultado esperado: 00 17:00:00
```

Sempre é levado em consideração a mudança de dia. No exemplo acima apesar de não ter completado 24h, o resultado de `DATEDIFF` já retorna 1 dia.

Comment: Você deveria incluir uma amostra do código de como está realizando as consultas para obter esse resultado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença entre duas datas em dias, horas, minutos e segundos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25162/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-duas-datas-em-dias-horas-minutos-e-segundos)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que é isto o que você quer

```
select CAST( '2018-01-01 17:00:01' AS DATETIME ) AS data_um,
        CAST( '2018-01-02 10:01:02' AS DATETIME ) AS data_dois,
        DATEDIFF( SECOND, CAST( '2018-01-01 17:00:01' AS DATETIME ),CAST( '2018-01-02 10:01:02' AS DATETIME ) ) / 60/ 60/ 24 AS difer_dias,
        DATEDIFF( SECOND, CAST( '2018-01-01 17:00:01' AS DATETIME ),CAST( '2018-01-02 10:01:02' AS DATETIME ) ) / 60/ 60 AS difer_horas,
        DATEDIFF( SECOND, CAST( '2018-01-01 17:00:01' AS DATETIME ),CAST( '2018-01-02 10:01:02' AS DATETIME ) ) / 60% 60 AS difer_minutos,
        DATEDIFF( SECOND, CAST( '2018-01-01 17:00:01' AS DATETIME ),CAST( '2018-01-02 10:01:02' AS DATETIME ) ) % 60 AS difer_segundos
```

Vai mostrar a quantia de segundos, minutos, horas e dias, de uma forma que se pode usar por extenso, por exemplo:

Se passaram `0` dias, `17` horas, `1` minuto e `1` segundo desde a última verificação.

Comment: Leandro, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Leandro, funcionou perfeitamente! O problema é que eu estava fazendo o DATADIFF usando 'DAY' para encontrar a diferença de dias. Daí era levado em conta somente a passagem de um dia para o outro. Ex: Data1: 2018-01-01 Data2: 2018-01-02, dava sempre diferença de 1 dia, não levando em conta as horas.

Comment: Uma dúvida que tive foi sobre essa parte CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEDIFF(SECOND, excur_start, excur_end) / 60% 60). Teria como me explicar essa expressão? "/ 60% 60"

Comment: Oi Leandro! Consegui decifrar a expressão! Coisa de matemático! rsrs

Comment: Este % é o MOD, traz como resultado o "resto" da divisão.