# Tabela MySQL com campo datetime, como saber quantos dias se passaram?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho uma tabela onde existem os seguintes campos.

```
prod_id [int 11]
prod_nome [varchar 100]
prod_desc [textarea]
prod_valor [double 10,2]
prod_data_cadastro [datetime]
```

Preciso criar um **SELECT** que mostra o tempo que passou até a data atual usando o registro da coluna **prod_data_cadastro** [datetime].

Tentei assim:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), `prod_data_cadastro`) as `data_corrida` FROM `produto` ORDER BY `data_corrida` DESC;
```

Mas me retorna apenas a quantidade de dias corridos, horas e minutos não, é possível trazer data e hora também?

Comment: Consegue dar um exemplo com uma data e o que você espera de resultado.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam A questão que você passou trata do SQL Server e não sobre MySQL. Abraço!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença entre duas datas em dias, horas, minutos e segundos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25162/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-duas-datas-em-dias-horas-minutos-e-segundos)

Comment: @rLinhares Mas lá, a questão fala sobre o banco é o SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posso te passar duas formas diferentes de se fazer isso. Lembrando que a comparação é feita com o horário do server.

1ª

```
SELECT CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(prod_data_cadastro,NOW())) / 24), ' dias ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(prod_data_cadastro, NOW())), 24), ' horas ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(prod_data_cadastro,NOW())), ' minutos') as `data_corrida`
FROM produto;
```

2ª

```
SELECT CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,prod_data_cadastro,NOW()) , ' dias ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,prod_data_cadastro,NOW()), 24), ' horas ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,prod_data_cadastro,NOW()), 60), ' minutos '
) as `data_corrida`
FROM produto;
```